# How can I get data in a callback function

Tags: ros, std-msgs, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have subscriber receive data from a topic. The message type is std_msgs::Bool. How can I access the data.
I tried ".data" which didn't give me the content.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44768/how-can-i-get-data-in-a-callback-function/) by [dustsnow](https://answers.ros.org/users/3238/dustsnow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on 2012-09-29**:
Do you want to recieve data in a callback function? Then try bool var = msg->Data;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why don't you look at the tutorials for [subscribers and publishers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)? Also take a look at the [bool message](http://ros.org/doc/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Bool.html) to figure it out.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5